# How to update every row in a table based on a counter value

Tags: sql

I am creating a table where I have an index column  which needs to be incremented for every row -

Id  Category Index

1. Dress    1
2. Shoes    2

Note that the index may not always start from 1. How can I achieve this?

I tried few things like using set -

```
UUPDATE table SET  index = NextId = NextId+1
```

but this didnt work

Comment: Did you consider using Autoincrement?

Maybe you could post the create statement of the table so that we can better help you with a solution. I am not 100% sure how to help

Comment: Mysql and google bigquery are two different database products with different implementations of sql. Removed conflicting product tags. Please add the one back that you actually use!

Comment: How is index different from the id column?

Comment: @Shadow - index helps in partitioning . Id is a string and index is just a pure integer and there is a partition defined based on values of index - 0-1000 go into 1st partition, 1000-2000 into 2nd and so on.

Comment: @JustinL - as I mentioned index may not always start from 1 or a single initial value.AFAIK there isnt any feature like this in auto increment.

Comment: Please tag the database your are using, along with sample data and expected tesult

Comment: Don't do this, it's a bad idea and will only cause you (and your co-workers) lots of problems for many years.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can use a user-defined variable to keep track of the index value and increment it for each row. Here's how you can do it:

```sql
SET @index = 1;

UPDATE your_table
SET `Index` = (@index := @index + 1)
ORDER BY `Index`;
```

This will update the `Index` column for each row in the table, starting from the value of `@index`. The `ORDER BY` clause ensures that rows are updated in the order specified by the `Index` column.

Make sure to replace `your_table` with the actual name of your table and `Index` with the actual name of your index column. Additionally, adjust the `ORDER BY` clause if you need to update rows in a different order.